# Condition obtained from semi-positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Given the correlation matrix:
$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho_{X Y} & \rho_{X Z} \\
\rho_{X Y} & 1 & \rho_{Y Z} \\
\rho_{X Z} & \rho_{Y Z} & 1
\end{array}\right)
$

How are the following conditions derived?

$
\begin{aligned}
&-\sqrt{\left(1-\rho_{X Y}^2\right)\left(1-\rho_{Y Z}^2\right)}+\rho_{X Y} \rho_{Y Z}\leq \rho_{X Z} \leq \sqrt{\left(1-\rho_{X Y}^2\right)\left(1-\rho_{Y Z}^2\right)}+\rho_{X Y} \rho_{Y Z} 
\end{aligned}
$

Those are not simply the non-negativeness of the determinants of the principal minors.

Comment: It originates from the fact that the inverse of a positive definite matrix is positive definite. Now consider the $(2,2)$-th minor of the inverse of the correlation matrix.